# Occasional loading problems in jquery modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, modal-dialog, colorbox

I'm using the [Colorbox script](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/blob/96f929a05d7f0e4ec2333fd7f1ecc5f00be85961/jquery.colorbox.js) in order to call an Outside Ajax HTML (located in my website, same server). You can see tha AJAX demo [in the official page of the plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

Sometimes I call the modal window automatically after some time, using:

```
  function openColorBox(){
    $.colorbox({
        transition: "elastic",
        opacity: 0.7,
        overlayClose: false,
        href: "/apop.html"});
  }
  setTimeout(openColorBox, 3000);
```

And sometime I use a POST request to pull it.

Either way, I noticed that sometimes it takes more than 1 seconds second to load, and once in a while, it keeps on showing the loading animation and never really load the file, so I have to close the modal window and try again.

What can be causing these performance problems? When I browse other websites I see many modal window that load right away, within milliseconds.

Should I stop using colorbox and move to another script? What can be a better performing alternative?